# changing linewidth and color in spBwplot

Tags: r

I want to increase the line width of the boxplot and change color. I have tried to do it in the following way but nothing happens.

```
spBwplot("var1", "weiht", dataS = dataS, dataP = listP, pch = "|", lwd=4, col="black")
```

Can somebody help me? Thank you.

Comment: where's this `spBwplot` available?

Answer (score 1):

As `spBwplot()` from library `simPopulation` for drawing boxplot use function `bwplot()` from `lattice` library then you can use the same parameters as in `lattice`.

To change boxplot box use `box.rectangle=` inside `par.settings()` and `box.umbrella=` to change whiskers. Argument `col=` will change color and `lwd=` will set line width.

Here is an example using data provided in help file of `spBwplot()`.

```
library(simPopulation)    
set.seed(1234)  # for reproducibility
data(eusilcS)   # load sample data
eusilcM <- simEUSILC(eusilcS, upper = 200000, equidist = FALSE)
eusilcT <- simEUSILC(eusilcS, method = "twostep")

spBwplot("netIncome", "rb050", "rb090", dataS = eusilcS, 
         dataP = list(M = eusilcM, T = eusilcT), layout = c(1, 2), 
         par.settings = list(box.rectangle = list(col = "black",lwd=4),
                             box.umbrella=list(lwd=4, col="black")))
```

[image]